# Create a list of tuples based on what a given element of another list is

Tags: lambda, prolog, tuples, primes, nested-lists

basically what I've managed to do is create a list of tuples in the form `A = [[1,2,3],[1,2,12],[1,2,5]]` using a fact `makelist(A)`.

What I want to do now is to use that to create another list where it only contains the tuples that are true for a given fact.

for example, I have a test that returns true if a number is prime `prime(N)` (which takes a number and returns true if it is prime) i want to use that to keep only the third elements in A that are prime. So `A = [[1,2,3],[1,2,5]]`

I've tried to use `predsort` but that seems to not work on only one element. I thought that it could be done using `exclude` but I can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [lambda.pl](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl), you could write:

```
:- [lambda].
filter_third_prime(Lists, Result) :-
    include(\[_, _, X|_]^prime(X), Lists, Result).
```

Without it you could write:

```
filter_third_prime2(Lists, Result) :-
    include(third_is_prime, Lists, Result).
third_is_prime([_, _, X|_]) :-
    prime(X).
```

BTW, you mentionned using `exclude/3`: those solutions are exactly alike ones using it, only they use its dual predicate, `include/3`.

Comment: @user1310221: you're welcome. Btw if you're used to functional programming idioms such as filter and map, I'd really advise you to take a look at the `lambda` library I linked, it will make your life that much more easy that it's worth learning it.

Answer (score 0):

```
% Assumes notPrime(N) is true iff N isn't prime
thirdPrimes([],[]).
thirdPrimes([A|B],[A|BP]) :- A=[_,_,N|_],prime(N),thirdPrimes(B,BP).
thirdPrimes([[_,_,N|_]|B],BP) :- notPrime(N),thirdPrimes(B,BP).
```